# PHP submit form with cUrl

Tags: php, curl

i want to submit any IP address to [this site](http://www.whatismyip.com/ip-whois-lookup/) with `cUrl` . my cUrl options could not work correctly:

```
  $h = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.whatismyip.com/ip-whois-lookup/"); 
  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
  'IP' => '2.179.144.117',
  'submitted' => 'submitted'
  ));
  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
  curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $result = curl_exec($h);
  echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your array data with `http_build_query()` function so that, it can be decoded correctly on requested IP:

```
curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(
   array(
      'IP' => '2.179.144.117',
      'submitted' => 'submitted'
   )
));
// echo http_build_query(array('IP' => '2.179.144.117', 'submitted' => 'submitted'));
// outputs: IP=2.179.144.117&submitted=submitted and this will be added to the end of
// the requested URL in GET request.
```

Comment: thanks. why i get this error: `403 Forbidden`. server of `whatismyip.com` does not allow access for cUrl?

Comment: I don't know how `whatismyip.com` service usage is, but 403 means the service doesn't allow your IP regardless of using cUrl.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check on the headers sent to that webpage, reveals that the "submitted" post variable should be set to true, not to submitted.

**Remark**: please note that whatismyip.com probably does not allow access to its tool by means of scraping.

Comment: As user3280126 also states, you should pass the post data as "IP=2.179.144.117&submitted=true". I must've looked over it.